# Seperate each character in a string and put it in a list

Tags: python, python-3.6

How would you go about separating each character in a given input and turn it into a list?

For example I have

```
import string
print ("Enter string")
x = input("")

Enter string
The quick brown
```

I want the end result to be

```
['T','h','e',' ','q','u','i','c','k',' ','b','r','o','w','n']
```

Y'know, to turn every **character** as a separate string in a list instead of every **word** as a separate string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `list(x)` where `x` is the string.

Comment: Should've realized this, Thanks!